# Failed to GroupBy with NHibernate LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I'm having hard times to perform simple grouping on my entities.
The faulting line of code is

```
var xxx = jobQuery.GroupBy(j => j.EverifyCase)
    .Select(g => new { EC = g.Key, MRJ = g.Last() })
    .ToList();
```

This gives me the following HibernateException:

> Query Source could not be identified: ItemName = < generated >_1,
>   ItemType = EverifyCaseJob,
>   Expression = from EverifyCaseJob _1 in [ec]

If I do `jobQuery.ToList()` everything is peachy - so I guess the problem is with the `GroupBy()` 
The "Query Source" **could** be identified as I use this entity all over the place, but not in conjunction with `GroupBy()` so far.

Any ideas?

Also, could anyone explain what the error message means?

NHibernate version is 4.0.3.4000

I also use Fluent NH - version 2.0.1.0

Comment: what is the type of `EverifyCase`?

Comment: `EverifyCase` is just another known, **properly** mapped entity, used all over the place. It is actually the master in the master-child relation with the EverifyCaseJob. The multiplicity of this relation is one-to-many.

Comment: The exception is broad, but it simply means that this type of query is not supported. The problem here with `.Last()`

Comment: @hazzik Yeah, I kind of felt this, because the `Max()` function works like a charm but it expects scalar.  Anyway, thank you for confirming this feeling :)

Answer (score 1):

Sql is set based and has no **order** in a grouping group. So it has no meaning of last in a group hence NHibernate can not translate it to sql. Max on the other side is well defined for a set and will work fine.